# What does `d for n` mean in sorted(d for n, d in G.degree())?

Tags: python, for-loop, networkx

I am learning the `networkx` library and I came across this (source code is [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html#analyzing-graphs))

```
sorted(d for n, d in G.degree())
```

which sorts the degrees of nodes in graph `G`. I don't quite understand this, especially `d for n`: what does `n` mean here?

Comment: `(n,d)` is a tuple. So `d` is its second element.

Comment: To be clear, this is a generator expression, not a list comprehension, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is shorthand for

```
lst = []
for n, d in G.degree():
   lst.append(d)
lst.sort()
```

So, `G.degree` is expected to return a set of tuples with two elements, where the second one has degrees.  You're just collecting those values and sorting them.